# error failed to build json gem native extension on windows 7x64

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rubygems, devkit

I am trying to install devkit and then to install json gem on Windows7 64bits, I have installed ruby 4.2.4 & extracted devkit configured config.yml and run ruby dk.rb install and then when i run gem install JSON --platform=ruby but it gives error as follows :

```
 current directory: C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
    C:/Ruby22/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160205-1668-13fh07v.rb extconf.rb
    creating Makefile

    current directory: C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
    make "DESTDIR=" clean

    current directory: C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
    make "DESTDIR="
    generating generator-i386-mingw32.def
    compiling generator.c
    In file included from c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby.h:33:0,
                     from ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5,
                     from generator.c:1:
    c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:111:14: error: size of array 'ruby_check_sizeof_voidp' is negative
    In file included from c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby.h:33:0,
                     from ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5,
                     from generator.c:1:
    c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_obj_freeze_inline':
    c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1156:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1157:2: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1158:6: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1158:27: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_data_object_get':
    c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1192:13: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_obj_written':
    c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1271:10: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1271:34: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_num2char_inline':
    c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1344:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1344:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1344:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1344:36: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1344:36: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1344:36: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1345:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1345:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1345:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_class_of':
    c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1670:12: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_type':
    c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1687:12: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    In file included from generator.c:1:0:
    ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h: In function 'fbuffer_append_str':
    ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:127:25: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:127:25: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:127:25: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c: In function 'convert_UTF8_to_JSON_ASCII':
    generator.c:129:35: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:129:35: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:129:35: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:130:38: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:130:38: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:130:38: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c: In function 'convert_UTF8_to_JSON':
    generator.c:227:23: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:227:23: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:227:23: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:228:25: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:228:25: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:228:25: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c: In function 'cState_configure':
    generator.c:553:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:553:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:553:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:554:34: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:554:34: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:554:34: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:561:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:561:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:561:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:562:33: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:562:33: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:562:33: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:569:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:569:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:569:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:570:40: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:570:40: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:570:40: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:577:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:577:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:577:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:578:36: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:578:36: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:578:36: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:585:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:585:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:585:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:586:37: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:586:37: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:586:37: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c: In function 'set_state_ivars':
    generator.c:634:21: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:634:21: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:634:21: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:636:24: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:636:24: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:636:24: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c: In function 'generate_json_object':
    generator.c:721:20: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:721:20: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:721:20: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c: In function 'generate_json_array':
    generator.c:767:20: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:767:20: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:767:20: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c: In function 'isArrayOrObject':
    generator.c:924:23: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:924:23: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:924:23: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:925:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:925:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:925:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c: In function 'cState_indent_set':
    generator.c:1049:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:1049:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:1049:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:1058:32: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:1058:32: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:1058:32: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c: In function 'cState_space_set':
    generator.c:1087:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:1087:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:1087:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:1096:31: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:1096:31: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:1096:31: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c: In function 'cState_space_before_set':
    generator.c:1123:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:1123:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:1123:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:1132:38: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:1132:38: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:1132:38: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c: In function 'cState_object_nl_set':
    generator.c:1161:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:1161:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:1161:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:1169:35: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:1169:35: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:1169:35: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c: In function 'cState_array_nl_set':
    generator.c:1196:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:1196:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:1196:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:1204:34: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:1204:34: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    generator.c:1204:34: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

    make failed, exit code 2
```

Comment: I have the exactly same error.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, I asked basically the same question and [Azolo noticed that it was because I had the wrong, x86 version of Ruby installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42282827/why-is-installing-the-json-1-8-6-gem-on-windows-8-not-working/42301154#42301154) instead of x64 which matches my machine and devkit. Deleting the old one and downloading an x64 version of Ruby fixed my issue.